# Expo React Native Wheelpicker Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

So far I have absoltuely loved using expo. But now, I would like to add a wheel picker (inline) to my app, it works fine on iOS but on Android it just shows a red outline. I think it has to do with needing to add custom build scripts, for this I would have to eject from expo; I really don't want to.

Is there another way I can implement a pickerview on android?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight-forward way to create a wheel-picker in react-native for android, especially when you're using Expo which restricts you from importing native code. What was your method of creating a wheel picker for iOS?

But maybe the standard react-native `Picker` component is viable for you? In contrast to iOS, a wheel picker is not considered a standard ui component in Android anyway. The normal `Picker` component will be rendered as a native android picker with a dropdown menu.

Straight from [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html):

```
import { Picker } from 'react-native'

// in your render method
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```